# Conversion operator converting to a class differing only in the template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I would like to be able to cast a class `A<double>` to `A<float>`. Here is what I tried:

```
#include<iostream>

template<class T1>
class A {
  template<class T0>
  operator A() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
};

template<class T0,class T1>
void bar( const A<T0>& a, const A<T1>& b )
{
  reinterpret_cast< const A<T0> >(b);
}


int main()
{
  A<float> a_f;
  A<double> a_d;
  bar(a_f,a_d);
}
```

The compiler spits: `error: invalid cast from type ‘const A<double>’ to type ‘const A<float>’`.

Is a conversion operator converting to a class differing only in the template argument possible? If yes: How?

Comment: A templated copy constructor, perhaps?

Comment: Perhaps. The reason why I want a cast is that the cast should be a no-op if its casted to the same type

Comment: "the cast should be a noop" does not make sense. do you mean that you want the normal copy constructor be chosen then? that will happen if you take the constructor template approach as well.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is almost never the solution. What do you really need? Do you need to interpret the memory as if it was of a different type? Or do you want to *translate* from one type to the other?

Comment: In case it's the same type it's casted to I would like to re-use the same instance/memory. If its a different type, then create a new instance. But both things accessible with the same API call, i.e. conversion to a different type. But it can also be some intelligent constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class T0> operator A<T0> ...
```

Without the template argument, its a conversion to `A<T1>`, i.e. a no-op.

Comment: Change your operator so that it looks like what I wrote. Yours doesn't use the template argument `T0`.

Comment: @Frank - change the `reinterpret_cast` to `static_cast`. There are still errors, but you should be able to fix them.

Comment: Yes, it calls it now. Have to look up the difference. But my issue is not solved yet. I'd like to return the same instance in case its a cast to the same class. However I think you answered the question